# Drag and drop between tabs and windows on IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-11, jquery-ui-draggable

I have two windows/tabs, let us call them W1 and W2. W2 is opened by W1 and they are using the same domain, but different pages. W1 contains a grid with workers and W2 contains a grid with jobs to do. I can assign a job by dragging a row (using jquery draggable) from W1 and dropping it to a row on W2. This works well under Chrome, FireFox, but not under IE 11.

If on IE 11 I start to drag a row and hover on the other page's tab/window and then drop, then nothing happens, no errors and the browser even lets me know that dropping to that window/tab is invalid by showing an invalid icon on that position. If W2 is inside an iframe in W1, then it works well.

Is this behavior fixable programmatically?

Comment: @user1844933 do you mean the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have contacted Microsoft to ask them about the issue I have experienced. It turns out that this kind of dragging is not supported in old Windows operating systems.

At the end of the conversation I asked the guy the following:

> so far I understood that this will work on Windows 10 MS browsers with
>   at least 1607 as version

He confirmed, so if anyone has such an issue with an MS browser, the op system version might be the cause.